# This bundle is invalid - Invalid XML character '0x10' at index 327 in Info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I have created my application which supports iOS7 and above. I archived my app and submitted to app store for app review. After successful uploading it says invalid binary and I got the email with following issue.

```
This bundle is invalid - Invalid XML character '0x10' at index 327 in Info.plist.
```

Can any one help me on this.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.domain.appname</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>appname</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>appname</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb13213213432312</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>13213213432312</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It seems that some issue is there with plist file. Try to check the contents of plist file if any special character is entered by mistake.I had faced same issue and reason was of unexpected character.

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora Is there any issue on Using FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName?

Comment: I cannot say without looking at the file. Can you please share the file?

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora I have attached my plist as image right, or do you need to view it in xml format?

Comment: XML would be better option.

Comment: Done the changes, please validate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48542/discussion-between-ganesh-and-pooja-maniklal-bohora)

Comment: <string>????</string> what is this??

Comment: @NitinGohel Bundle creator OS Type Code, That's not required right?

Comment: You've redacted the screenshots to not show your FaceBookAppID, but then you've pasted the whole XML where everything is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy and paste the xml content shared above in a new plist file and set it as a info.plist in build setting of the project. I have used the same xml and created plist to check the issue but it seems to be working perfect at my end.